# Tensorflow unwanted subgraphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to build a TFLite model which is composed of efficientdet for detection and keras-ocr (just the recognizer model) for recognition and I need it to run on mobile devices somewhat fast.
I want to fully quantize the model but it turns out the model has some subgraphs when inspecting it in [Netron](https://netron.app/) and TFLite doesn't support quantization of models with subgraphs.

[List of subgraphs in model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymtz7.png)

Here is the functional model definition I'm using and the layer which I think generates the subgraph.

```py
MAX_DETECTIONS = 10

img_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1080, 1920, 3), batch_size = 1)
boxes, scores, classes, _ = efficient_det_model_keras.model(img_inputs)
crops = CroppingLayer(MAX_DETECTIONS)(img_inputs, boxes, scores)
recognitions = RecognitionLayer(recognizer.prediction_model, MAX_DETECTIONS)(crops)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=img_inputs, outputs=(recognitions, scores), name="alpr")
```

```py
class CroppingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, MAX_RECOGNITIONS):
        super(CroppingLayer, self).__init__()
        self.MAX_RECOGNITIONS = MAX_RECOGNITIONS
        self.threshold = 0.3
    
    def get_crop(self, input_image, ymin, xmin, height, width):
        cropped = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(input_image, ymin, xmin, height, width)
        cropped = tf.image.resize(cropped, (31, 200))

        cropped = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(cropped)/255
        
        return cropped
    
    
    def call(self, input_image, boxes, scores):
        res = []

        ymin = tf.cast(boxes[0, :, 0], tf.int32)
        xmin = tf.cast(boxes[0, :, 1], tf.int32)
        ymax = tf.cast(boxes[0, :, 2], tf.int32)
        xmax = tf.cast(boxes[0, :, 3], tf.int32)
        height = tf.math.abs(ymax - ymin)
        width = tf.math.abs(xmax - xmin)

        for i in range(self.MAX_RECOGNITIONS):
            cropped = self.get_crop(input_image[0], ymin[i], xmin[i], height[i], width[i])

            res.append(cropped)

        batch = [tf.stack(res, axis = 0)]

        return tf.stack(batch, axis = 0)
```

Is there any way I can get rid of these subgraphs to make a single graph model?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the for loop statement led to create a control flow op in the TensorFlow graph. If the recognition number can be fixed, unlooping the for loop statement may help creating a single subgraph.

Comment: Changing self.MAX_RECOGNITIONS in the loop to a set integer doesn't fix the issue. My only hint at this point is that one of the arguments in the loop condition is "alpr/cropping_layer_5/crop_to_bounding_box/strided_slice1". I think it might have to do with how crop_to_bounding_box is implemented, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Setting an integer is not enough Unlooping the for loop will help getting rid of the TF control flow op dependency. For example, cropped_0 = self.get_crop(input_image[0], ymin[0], xmin[0], height[0], width[0])
cropped_1 = self.get_crop(input_image[1], ymin[1], xmin[1], height[1], width[1]) ...
res.append(cropped_0)
res.append(cropped_1) ....

Comment: I've tried that and I still get the same subgraphs :/ I've also tried using tf.image.crop_and_resize (https://pastebin.com/VRW20J47) and it's still not working.

Comment: I guess the cropping layer is just one of layers of your model. There are other layers creating control ops. It would be better to share the reproducible model code if possible.

Comment: Here is a gist of my code (https://gist.github.com/bhuminiecki/0a555dd63f8f5066c150e42e4d438cc8) and the trained efficientdet model here (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jofauMTE0h5NiPTXadzZH-5pj0bI4P5y?usp=sharing). EfficientDet is trained using the official script from automl with 1920x1080 input size and 10 detections per image.